# Apache Camel RouteBuilder configure method

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, apache-camel

I have some existing web application program develop by pass senior and now I am supporting and study on it. I tried to read many articles from internet about the Apache Camel, but still cant get the point.

Let me show some Class code that extends `RouteBuilder`:

This is from `FserviceRouteBuilder` class:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    log.debug( "FServiceRouteBuilder configure" );
    errorHandler( deadLetterChannel( ).maximumRedeliveries( 0 ) );

    from( this.from ).process( requestProcessor ).process(
            transformProcessor );

    log.debug( "FServiceRouteBuilder configure end" );

}
```

And this is from `MyBillRouteBuilder` :

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    log.debug( ">>MybillRouteBuilder configure" );
    errorHandler( deadLetterChannel( ).maximumRedeliveries( 0 ) );

    from( this.from ).process( requestProcessor ).to(
            "direct:_mybill-process-response" );

    if ( transformProcessor != null ) {
        from( "direct:_mybill-process-response" ).process(
                transformProcessor );
    }

    log.debug( ">>MybillRouteBuilder configure end" );

}
```

What I saw from the different is, the `MyBillRouteBuilder` use the `to()` method, which is `to( "direct:_myebill-process-response" )` , but `FServiceRouteBuilder` didn't do in that way.

But both of them work. I tried to change the `FServiceRouteBuilder` to follow to use the `to()` method, and its work as well.

Both of them also calling and processing particular web service with SOAP method.

May I know what is the `to()` actually doing? And what is the different to use it and without it?

Sorry I am very very new to this.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that in FServiceRouteBuilder all the steps in your route runs in the same Thread.

```
from( this.from ).process( requestProcessor ).process(
        transformProcessor );
```

Both the processors(requestProcessor, transformProcessor) runs in the same Thread. You can confirm this by just logging a statement in both processor like `Thread.currentThread().getId()`.

Whereas with MyBillRoutebuilder your second processor(transformProcessor) is decoupled from first(using a `to`) and it runs in a separate thread.

```
from( this.from ).process( requestProcessor ).to(
            "direct:_mybill-process-response" );

if ( transformProcessor != null ) {
    from( "direct:_mybill-process-response" ).process(
                transformProcessor );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Conclusion can I said that they are still doing the same thing, the different is 1 separate to different thread, and another 1 using the same thread?

Comment: Yes. Couple of points. You need to decide which is better for you based on the kinda operation you are doing in these two processors. are those operations thread safe, is it okay if they run in separate threads and do they need to run sequentially. If you are okay running them in separate threads, then i would go for that (using `to`), because, you get this threading behavious without writing and thread code. Do accpet/upvote. :)